# Link to other document's title in DocBook

Tags: docbook

I'm putting together a few documents using DocBook.  Almost all of them will refer to each other in some way, so I put together a bibliography section (using `<bibliography`).  Is there some way, e.g. using `<olink>`, to automatically pull in the titles of the other documents?

```
<biblioentry id="foo">
  <abbrev>FOO</abbrev>
  <title>what do I put here?</title
</biblioentry>
```

Answer (score -1):

These is a way to put all biblio entries into one document. As a kind of library. Each document which then requires some reference to another document, can include the references from that library as required. (I'll update this answer soon with an example.)